# Authenticate to Azure Log Analytics Api using OAuth2.0 Client credentials

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to access my Azure app registered in Azure Active Directory(AAD). I am using the OAuth2.O Client credential protocol (https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Authorization/OAuth2).

Using the Rest client (Postman) I am able to connect. But I need to do the same in my Java application.

There are 2 steps in connection

1. To get the access-token.

   ```
   POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_AAD_TENANT/oauth2/token    
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   grant_type=client_credentials
   &client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &resource=https://management.azure.com/
   &client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
   ```
2. To make a request to the workspace using the access token

   ```
   POST https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/8fXXXXX-0a84-XXX-XXX- c1a5XXXXXX/query?timespan=P1D

   Authorization: Bearer [access_token]      
   {
       "query": "AzureActivity | limit 10"
   }
   ```

Can someone help me to write a java client to do above? I referred to the following links:

- [Authenticate to Azure API App using ADAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489604/authenticate-to-azure-api-app-using-adal)
- [Authenticate to an Azure API App from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891305/authenticate-to-an-azure-api-app-from-java)

But they do not use the Tenant id and grant type not `client_credentials`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code smaple as below, use `authResult.getAccessToken()` to get the access token, it should work.

```
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential; // for service principal

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

// Account specific values
String tenantId = <your tenant id>
String clientId = <your client id>
String password = <your password>

// use adal to Authenticate
AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
ExecutorService service = null;

try {
    service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/authorize";
    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(url,
                                            false,
                                            service);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, password);
        Future<AuthenticationResult>  future = authContext.acquireToken(
                                                        "https://management.azure.com/",
                                                        clientCred,
                                                        null);
    authResult = future.get();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception as needed
} finally {
    service.shutdown();
}
```

For more details, see this [link](http://innerdot.com/azure/authenticating-to-azure-resource-manager-using-java).